# Measures, as a supreme, proof

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $\Sigma$ be a $σ$-algebra over a set $X$, and $μ_1$ and $μ_2$ finite measures in it. It can be shown that the function $μ:\Sigma \to [0,\infty ]$ defined by

$$E\mapsto \sup_{F∈\Sigma}\{μ_1(E∩F)+μ_2(E\setminus F)\}$$

is a measure.

could someone help me see is a measure

I got stuck when i have to show

$$\mu(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_n) \geqslant \sum_{n=1}^\infty\sup_{F\in\Sigma} \left\{\mu_1(E_n\cap F) + \mu_2(E_n\setminus F) \right\} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \nu(E_n).$$

$E_n $ a secuence of disjoints set

Know you can also use Radon-Nicodym, since $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ finite, but i'm more interested in the general case, when you have two measures

Comment: I've attempted to clean up your seemingly copied-and-pasted bit of notation, but I'm still trying to figure out what was intended.  Can you clarify? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Sorry, i'm not sure how to say it, but the problem, is tha i'm not able to proove that $$\sup_{F∈\Sigma}\{μ_1(E∩F)+μ_2(E\setminus F)\}$$ is a measure
thanks for correcting me, and sorry for my english

Comment: Can you use the Radon-Nikodym theorem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We only need to prove 
$$
\nu(E)=\nu(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_n) \geqslant \sum_{n=1}^\infty \nu(E_n)$$
as another case is proved in @Math1000's post.

First we prove
$$
\nu(E_1\cup E_2)\geqslant \nu(E_1)+\nu(E_2)
$$
for disjoint $E_1$ and $E_2$.

By definition of $\nu$, there exist $F_1,F_2\in\Sigma$ such that
$$
\mu_1(E_1\cap F_1) + \mu_2(E_1\setminus F_1)\geqslant \nu(E_1)-\epsilon\quad\text{and}\quad \mu_1(E_2\cap F_2) + \mu_2(E_2\setminus F_2)\geqslant \nu(E_2)-\epsilon
$$
So 
\begin{align}
\nu(E_1\cup E_2)&\geqslant \mu_1((E_1\cup E_2)\cap (F_1\cup F_2)) + \mu_2(E_1\cup E_2\setminus F_1\cap F_2)
\\
&=\mu_1((E_1\cap (F_1\cup F_2))\cup (E_2\cap (F_1\cup F_2)) + \mu_2((E_1\setminus F_1\cap F_2)\cup (E_2\setminus (F_1\cap F_2))
\\
&=\mu_1(E_1\cap (F_1\cup F_2))+\mu_1( E_2\cap (F_1\cup F_2))+\\&\hspace{10 mm}\mu_2(E_1\setminus F_1\cap F_2)+\mu_2(E_2\setminus F_1\cap F_2)
\\
&\geqslant \mu_1(E_1\cap F_1)+\mu_1( E_2\cap F_2)+\mu_2(E_1\setminus F_1)+\mu_2(E_2\setminus F_2)
\\
&=\nu(E_1)+\nu(E_2)-2\epsilon
\end{align}
Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary small, we have
$$
\nu(E_1\cup E_2)\geqslant \nu(E_1)+\nu(E_2)
$$
Thus
$$
\nu(E_1\cup E_2)=\nu(E_1)+\nu(E_2)\tag{1}
$$
Next we prove 
$$
E_1\subset E_2\implies \nu(E_1)\leqslant \nu(E_2)\tag{2}
$$
Since for any $F\in\Sigma$
$$
\mu_1(E_1\cap F) + \mu_2(E_1\setminus F)\leqslant \mu_1(E_2\cap F) + \mu_2(E_2\setminus F)
$$
So
$$
\nu(E_1)=\sup\{\mu_1(E_1\cap F) + \mu_2(E_1\setminus F)\}\leqslant \sup\{\mu_1(E_2\cap F) + \mu_2(E_2\setminus F)\}=\nu(E_2)
$$
Finally for any disjoint $E_n$, since 
$$\bigcup_{n\leqslant m}E_n \subset \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} E_n$$
By (1) and (2), there is
$$
\sum_{n\leqslant m}\nu(E_n)=\nu(\bigcup_{n\leqslant m} E_n)\leqslant \nu(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}E_n)
$$
Let $m\to\infty$, it is proved.

Comment: $$\nu(E_1\cup E_2) = sup(\mu_1((E_1\cup E_2)\cap (F_1\cup F_2)) + \mu_2(E_1\cup E_2\setminus F_1\cup F_2)) $$
$$\geqslant \mu_1((E_1\cup E_2)\cap (F_1\cup F_2)) + \mu_2(E_1\cup E_2\setminus F_1\cap F_2)$$ 
i'm los in that inecuality, maybe is trivial but, i'm not able to see it

Comment: Since $\nu(E_1∪E_2)=\sup$ is reached for some $F$, it may not be $F_1∪F_2$. But $\sup$ is always larger than other $F$.

Comment: $$\nu(E_1\cup E_2) = sup(\mu_1((E_1\cup E_2)\cap F_1) + \mu_2(E_1\cup E_2\setminus F)) $$
$$\geqslant \mu_1((E_1\cup E_2)\cap (F_1\cup F_2)) + \mu_2(E_1\cup E_2\setminus F_1\cup F_2)$$
$$\geqslant \mu_1((E_1\cup E_2)\cap (F_1\cup F_2)) + \mu_2(E_1\cup E_2\setminus F_1\cap F_2)$$ 

i undertand it like you are telling me that,

Comment: 1st line $F$ could be different and 2nd line should be $μ_2(E_1∪E_2∖F_1\cap F_2)$. 2nd line $F$ could be different too.

Comment: $$\nu(E_1\cup E_2) =sup\mu_1((E_1\cup E_2)\cap (F) + \mu_2(E_1\cup E_2\setminus F) $$
$$\geqslant \mu_1((E_1\cup E_2)\cap (F_1\cup F_2)) + \mu_2(E_1\cup E_2\setminus F_1\cup F_2)$$
$$\geqslant \mu_1((E_1\cup E_2)\cap (F_1\cup F_2)) + \mu_2(E_1\cup E_2\setminus F_1\cap F_2)$$ is this what you are tryin to tell me?

Comment: Yes, except 2nd line should be $μ_1((E_1∪E_2)∩(F_1∪F_2))+μ_2(E_1∪E_2∖F_1\cap F_2)$

Answer (score 2):

Let $$\nu(E) = \sup_{F\in\Sigma}\{\mu_1(E\cap F) + \mu_2(E\setminus F)\}.$$
Then for any $F\in\Sigma$, $$\mu_1(\varnothing\cap F)+\mu_2(\varnothing\setminus F) = \mu_1(\varnothing) + \mu_2(\varnothing) = 0.$$
If $E_n$ is a sequence of disjoint sets in $\Sigma$, let $E=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_n$. Then for any $F\in\Sigma$,
$$\mu_1(E\cap F)=\mu_1\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (E_n\cap F)\right) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu_1(E_n\cap F), $$
and similarly
$$\mu_2(E\setminus F)=\mu_2\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (E_n\setminus F)\right) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu_2(E_n\setminus F).$$
Hence
$$
\nu(E) = \sup_{F\in\Sigma}\left\{\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu_1(E_n\cap F) + \mu_2(E_n\setminus F) \right\}$$
and so $$\nu(E) \leqslant \sum_{n=1}^\infty\sup_{F\in\Sigma} \left\{\mu_1(E_n\cap F) + \mu_2(E_n\setminus F) \right\} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \nu(E_n).$$
It remains to show the reverse inequality. (I got stuck here :/ )

Comment: Sugestion: in $\sup_{F\in\Sigma} \left\{\mu_1(E_n\cap F) + \mu_2(E_n\setminus F) \right\}$ you can, WLOG,  consiser only $F\subseteq E_n$. So we have $\sup_{F\in\Sigma} \left\{\mu_1(E_n\cap F) + \mu_2(E_n\setminus F) \right\}=\sup_{F_n\in\Sigma \textrm{ and } F_n\subseteq E_n} \left\{\mu_1(E_n\cap F_n) + \mu_2(E_n\setminus F_n) \right\}$.

Comment: Then use the disjoint union $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty F_n$ in the expression of $\nu(E)$ to show that $$\nu(E) \geqslant \sum_{n=1}^\infty\sup_{F\in\Sigma} \left\{\mu_1(E_n\cap F) + \mu_2(E_n\setminus F) \right\}.$$